# how to have different uv sheets for some objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I have a tank model and the thing is there are some objects with seperate uv sheets. I can't join the model together into one because if i do then this happens:

[image]

I have tried a uv map node and an attribute node for each material but when i join them i still get this, only one shows up. Also i don't wanna create a material for each part of the model..I asked yesterday but i didn't word it quite good enough. I have four main materials that i use all over the mesh, if i connect one to one uv map then all of them will be connected to that one uv map.

Comment: You probably misunderstand something. Every UV map contains the whole mesh, if you can't see every faces in the UV editor, they are in the left bottom corner in one dot. Multiple UV Maps are not for the different parts of the meshes. If you want to use multiple materials for different parts of the mesh it is not a problem they intersect each other. Use the whole space for every single material, but only on one UV map. After joining the meshes you can't merge UV maps, so make sure they have the same name before the joining.

Comment: probably since im pretty confused. I uv unwrapped everything, and i have multiple uv sheets, everything has been unwrapped. I cant put everything on one map i have wayy too many details. multiple objects have the same material so i cant bind them all to one map without causing issues. Should i post a blend?

Comment: Yes, post it please.